# Maintain 5 threads at a time in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java application that sends requests to the server and returns me the response. The requests are run on separate threads each.

What I want to do is maintain 5 threads at a time (hence, 5 requests going at a time). Also, if a thread finishes, I want to start a new thread so that 5 threads are running at all times.

Initially I thought I could use join when calling the thread, but realized that will block my main thread.

Is there a way to get this done? I haven't programmed in Java much and am open to any suggestions/advice.

Comment: You can use a ThreadPool (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Comment: try to think in jobs/tasks, not threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use an ExecutorService

```
Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for(String url: urls) 
   exec.submit(new UrlTask(urls));

// when finished
exec.shutdown();
```

This will perform up to 5 tasks at once.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for something like [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with fixed thread pool.

```
ExecutorService  pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to write this from scratch using `Thread`.

I'd recommend setting up an `Executor` pool and doing [producer/consumer](http://www.javabeat.net/2012/06/implementing-producer-consumer-scenario-using-blockingqueue-java/) with a `BlockingDeque`.

Comment: Why a BlockingDeque rather than a ConcurrentLinkedQueue as the Executors utility does? Given the ExecutorService has a built in queue, I would use that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - ConcurrentLinkedQueue blocks?  If not, what are the threads to do if there are no tasks?

Comment: @MartinJames No, my mistake, it is `LinkedBlockingQueue` which does. But it's not a Deque.

Comment: What do threads do if there are no tasks?  Wait until they arrive, of course.  The consumer will take them from the queue and dole them out to the executors.